# Jquery mobile submit form with a dialog (straight POST)

Tags: jquery, forms, mobile, dialog, submit

I am building a mobile web app using the jquery mobile framework.  I need to have my submit form button open up a dialog popup as well.  But the input type ="submit" element does not allow for the href attribute that's used to popup the dialog page.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is the html.  It pops up the dialog but does not submit the form.

```
      <a data-role="button" href="ManholePhotosDialog.aspx" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop"class="save">Submit</a>
```

I tried this script but it isn't working:

```
$(".save").click(function (){
  $("#form1").submit()
});
```

Comment: Show us the how the form looks like

Answer (score 1):

I was stumped on this one as well. JQueryMobile is nice, but it really messes with traditional JQuery techniques. Put this on the page that launches the dialog and you should be good to go.

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#save", function()
{
    $("#form1").submit()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit the form to `href` of `a` tag then try something like this:

```
$(".save").click(function (){
  $("#form1").attr('action', $(this).attr('href')).submit()
});
```

Comment: I am submitting the form to the page itself. Its input type ="file" for photo uploads and I am using C# postback to store the data in a database..

Comment: the dialog popup is just to show that the photos have been submitted.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use a post because it is using input type="file".  My answer so far was to use    Response.Redirect("PhotoUploadComplete.aspx"); to bring up a dummy page with the anchor and href to the dialog popup. But its not quite working yet.